# RegEx within perl -pi -e

Tags: regex, perl

Say for example I have this in a file:

```
<example id="1">some text</example>
<example id="2">some other text</example>
<example id="3">random words</example>
```

I want to use `perl -pi -e` to remove `<example` and `</example>` which I can do easily, but I'm not sure how I can do it to also remove everything within these two tags.

I can currently get rid of the `<example` and `</example>` by doing this:

```
perl -pi -e 's/<example//g' /file.xml; perl -pi -e 's/<\/example>//g' /file.xml;
```

But obviously this still leaves the rest of the text.

Any ideas?

Comment: You want to remove the entirety of your text? `perl -pi -e 's/.+//' /file.xml`

Comment: will the end tag always be on the same line as the start tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do:

```
perl -pi'~' -e "s/<example.*?>.+?<\/example>//g" file.xml
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to quote the tilde? Don't think so. But quoting the replace expression with single quotes instead of double quotes makes sense.

Comment: Hi ceving, I guess you are on Linux, not Windows