# Unix/Linux/FreeBSD Find Command with Perl Regex

Tags: regex, linux, perl, unix, find

I would like to swap out every instance of "/this/name/" with "/that/name/" (within the files of a directory) - I'm just not sure how.

Is there a good way of combining the two commands below (or something equivalent) to search/regex an entire directory of files recursively?

```
•    perl -pi -e "s/2f\x74\x68\x69\x73\x2f\x6e\x61\x6d\x65\x2f/\2f\x74\x68\x61\x74\x2f\x6e\x61\x6d\x65\x2f/g" /some/directory

•    find . -name "*"
```

The first Perl example works fine for an individual file, just not a bunch of them. The Find example is of course just an example. I've used these two previous questions as some reference:

[Find] [Unix find: multiple file types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190565/unix-find-multiple-file-types)

[Perl] [RegEx within perl -pi -e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104759/regex-within-perl-pi-e)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, use the `-exec` flag of `find`

```
find /path -type f -exec perl -pi -e "..." {} \;
```

I added `-type f` because I think you want to execute this for files only.

Comment: cool, i will try it asap. one more question, would it be possible to have the `find /path -type f -exec` actually execute a shell script or perl script as in `find /path -type f -exec sh script.sh {} \;` or something along those lines? thanks!